# Eslint: "Unexpected token /" on jsx

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to configure eslint to work with react:

This is my `.eslintrc` file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    amd: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended"],
  globals: {
    Atomics: "readonly",
    SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly",
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": [2],
    indent: ["warn", 2],
    "linebreak-style": ["warn", "unix"],
    quotes: ["warn", "double"],
    semi: ["warn", "always"],
  },
};
```

And this is my `index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App.js";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The thing keeps complaining about the slash on `<App />`:

```
6:22  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token /
```

I'm not sure whats going on. How can I get rid of that error?

Comment: maybe `babel-eslint` will help ? install it and also add it in the parser

Comment: It was an issue with eslint 5, I downgraded to 4 and now it works fine

Comment: I think you should use `babel-eslint` parser anyway as was suggested to not downgrade